# Use substr to get string with possible different lengths

Tags: php

I am sure this is a super basic question but I can't find the solution anywhere.

I am using substr to get the value from some html code posted through a form:

```
$id = substr($html, 23, 1);
```

This works if the id in the html is just 1 digit. But I need to be able to get the id, of any length. The id in the $html variable is surrounded by double quotes e.g.

```
$html = '<p>This is a test for "1" stackoverflow</p>'
```

In the above example I get `1` but if the id is 13, it would still return `1`.

Can I use the closing double-quotes as a stop character?

EDIT:

There will be other double quotes in the `$html` so i can't just look for double quotes. It has to be the very next double-quotes to the position in the `substr()` (in this example - 23)

Comment: You can use regex `$html.match(/"(\d+)"/)[1]`

Comment: Try this `<?Php
$html = '<p>This is a test for "112"  "23" stackoverflow</p>';
$regex = '/"(\d+)"/';
if( preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches))
{
    print_r($matches[1][0]);
    // echo $matches[1]
}
?>`